# Laravel Bulk Insert To Another Table From Selected Multiple Rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I expected I can replicate multiple row from specific table to another table. But the problem, it cannot replicate password field data and spatie `assignRole()`. Whereas, all fields like email, name, username, etc are works properly.

```
public function approveMultiple(Request $request) {
        $get_ids = $request->ids;
        $ids = explode(',', $get_ids);

        $users = \App\Applicant::whereIn('id', $ids);
        $users->update(['status' => 'Approved']); 

        $find_selected = \App\Applicant::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
        $find_selected->makeHidden(['status', 'id']);
        $find_selected->makeVisible(['password']);
        $new_users = $find_selected->toArray();
        $users = \App\User::insert($new_users);

        //problem still lays here
        //$users->assignRole('Applicant');
        //$users->save();

        return response()->json(['success' => "Selected User(s) successfully approved."]);
    }
```

Trying to this approach but only insert one record

```
public function approveMultiple(Request $request) {
        $get_ids = $request->ids;
        $ids = explode(',', $get_ids);

        //$users = \App\Applicant::whereIn('id', $ids);
        //$users->update(['status' => 'Approved']); 

        //$find_selected = \App\Applicant::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
        $find_selected = \App\Applicant::whereIn('id', $ids)->firstOrFail();
        $find_selected->makeHidden(['status', 'id']);
        $find_selected->makeVisible(['password']);
        $new_users = $find_selected->toArray();
        //$users = \App\User::insert($new_users);


        $users = \App\User::create([
            'name' => $find_selected->name,
            'username' => $find_selected->username,
            'gender' => $find_selected->gender,
            'email' => $find_selected->email,
            'phone' => $find_selected->phone,
            'password' => $find_selected->password,
            'created_at' => $find_selected->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $find_selected->updated_at,
        ]);

        //problem lays here
        $users->assignRole('Applicant');
        $users->save();

        return response()->json(['success' => "Selected User(s) successfully approved."]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

about password field , you need to make it visible with function like : `makeVisible`

for example:

```
$users->makeVisible('password')->toArray();
```

## Edit 1:

about `assignRole` you must assign the role after you call the `save()` method

for example:

```
$users->password = $find_selected->password;
$users->save();
$users->assignRole('Applicant');
```

## Edit 2:

```
public function approveMultiple(Request $request) {
        $get_ids = $request->ids;
        $ids = explode(',', $get_ids);

        //$users = \App\Applicant::whereIn('id', $ids);
        //$users->update(['status' => 'Approved']); 

        $find_selected = \App\Applicant::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
        //$find_selected = \App\Applicant::whereIn('id', $ids)->firstOrFail();
        $find_selected->makeHidden(['status', 'id']);
        $find_selected->makeVisible(['password']);
        $new_users = $find_selected->toArray();
        //$users = \App\User::insert($new_users);

        foreach($find_selected as $new_users){
           $user = \App\User::create($new_users);
           $user->assignRole('Applicant');
        }

        return response()->json(['success' => "Selected User(s) successfully approved."]);
    }
```

Comment: call to member function assignRole() on bool

Comment: @SeadLab can you please make a pastebin.com of the code or update the question

Comment: `Model::insert()` will return a boolean in some cases.

Why aren't you using the standard `Model::create([array $data])`. This will return the object of the created user, which you can then run assignRole against.

Comment: I made it like this, `$users = \App\User::create($new_users);`, yes `assignRole()` is work, but the rest of fields not working at all

Comment: @SeadLab rest of fields like what ?

Comment: rest of fields like email, name, username, etc

Comment: add `assignRole` after `save()` ! check the answer again @SeadLab

Comment: NULL no data entered

Comment: I am sorry.. I mean only entered one record

Comment: It's really NULL

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem lays in this line:

```
$users = \App\User::insert($new_users);
```

insert method returns a boolean that indicate the insertion operation has succeeded or not ...
so you $users variable will hold a boolean value ... 
and

```
$users->assignRole('Applicant');
 $users->password = $find_selected->password;
```

wont work

you could use  :

```
$find_selected->makeVisible(['password']);

foreach($find_selected as $user)
{
$newUser= new User();
$newUser->password = $user->password;
$newUser->save();
$newUser->assignRole('Applicant');
}
```

Comment: after $newUser->save(); please write  $newUser->refresh(); then try ...

Comment: I think you're wrong. `$newUser->save();`. Where is reference `$newUser`? I've updated the code please check!

Comment: try dd(  $users)  after $users = \App\User::insert($new_users); it is boolean value